# From my Mobile App how can I log in to WordPress using Google Auth?

Tags: ios, wordpress, oauth, xamarin.forms, google-authentication

I'm developing a Xamarin forms mobile app (iOS). I would like the user of the mobile app to be authenticated by google auth in order to access WordPress (a.k.a. WP henceforth) Resources. I see the flow as follows:

1. User launches the Mobile App and is presented with the WP login screen where along with the WP login fields, there is a button that says 'Login with Google'.
2. Upon tapping on the 'Login with Google' button, the user is redirected to Google's login page where he/she enters Google credentials.
3. Google then redirects back in either one of the ways:

   a. Google redirects to WP with necessary tokens which in turn redirects to the app with necessary tokens.

   b. Google redirects back directly to the app with the necessary tokens.

Is this a valid scenario?

I know that Xamarin Forms has packages that support OAuth so that can be handled, but how would I go about setting this up between WP and Google Auth? What would the correct Redirect URL's be?

Appreciate any help that can be provided.

Thanks & Regards

Noel